# I am facing an issue in c

Tags: c, windows

I have recently started to learn programming in c language. I installed Mingw and vista studio code for the same. However, when I wrote my first program it just keeps showing error and won't run. I made a program to calculate simple interest. I have checked the syntax multiple times. Please help in pointing out the error.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int p, n;
   float r, si;

   printf("Enter principal\n Enter no. of years\n Enter rate\n");
   scanf("%d, %d, %f", &p, &n, &r);
   si = p * r * n / 100;
   printf("%f\n", si);
   return 0;
}
```

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kttB7.png)

Comment: Please include the code and the error as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 3):

The `gcc` executable is not on your `PATH`, and so the system can't find it (and thus not execute it)

Update the `PATH` environment variable so that the directory where gcc is installed is part of it.

[See here for how to do that.](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/)